Why we are coded with the idea of religion and its concepts if we are living in a computer simulation?
We all know that Nick Bostrom's cliche argument in favor of Simulation Hypothesis.
I am wondering if my question can downgrade the Bostrom's hypothesis.
Lets assume that we are living in a computer simulation created by our post human ancestor civilization.
Since all meanings we know are coded in such simulator, What can be the reason of coding the idea of theism, God, religion and their concepts such as escatology, prophets, scriptures and etc. into the simulation?
Why should they want to manupulate us with the afterlife?
Why are they hiding theirselves  and forwarding our interest to another creator? What can be the reason?
I appreciate your answers and thoughts.

Maybe the "coder" want to be worshipped as God...

@MauroALLEGRANZA that taked us to Theism as well.

@MauroALLEGRANZA who created this advanced simulators anyway?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, "Maybe the "coder" want to be worshipped as God..."  If a coder created, us then by definition that coder is God.

Echoing other responses, why would such a thing need to be coded directly into the system?  If anything, our experience suggests that if this is a simulation, thoughts are formed much more abstractly than any hard coding of particular concepts.  Our brain exhibits brain plasticity, and therefore is able to "rewire" itself based on stimulus around it, which suggests concepts arent hard coded, but develop over time with the brain.
But we dont understand the brain and thoughts perfectly well, so let's grant the assumption that religion was hard coded as a concept.  Even then, in Bostroms hypothesis, it is an "ancestor simulation".
For the ancestor simulation to be accurate, presumably the simulated ancestors cannot be truly aware they are in a simulation, or else that knowledge would impact the actions of the simulated ancestors, and would make the simulation inaccurate.  Now, if we follow your assumption, that all concepts are hard coded into the simulation, why would the one who created the simulation allow us to conceptualize Bostrom's Simulation Hypothesis if the hypothesis were accurate?
That would ruin the simulation, unless we assume to accurately simulate ancestors, ideas either arent hard coded, or the hard coding reflects all possible thoughts of the ancestors being simulated, even if those are false (or if true knowledge of them would ruin the simulation).

thank you for the best answer. Of course for me. Thats my issue as well. This slippery  hypothesis is full of maybes and huge blanks. All we are trying to do is triying to read the ancestor's mind if so.

It depends on the nature of simulation. It could be that the idea of gods etc is not something that has been explicitly coded. It could be that they have simulated minds that are capable of dreaming up ideas for themselves, so gods are a product of the simulated minds not a hard-coded feature of the simulation.

Isn't it interesting to create a God idea as a product for simulated minds even if so?

There are some assumptions in your question. For instance: All the meaning we know are in the simulator. Well, maybe take a step back and look into the modern aspect of "coding". Generally speaking, for an object-oriented coded system to be meaningful, it should consist of two major parts: 1. The definition of the properties of the entities. 2. The definition of behaviors of the entities.
For a coder to achieve a meaningful system, it's not necessarily required to purposefully code the properties and the behaviors. They can be acquired by a lower-level code itself. Take a look at machine learning method in which the system evolve itself based on the inputs it receives. (The input may or may not be generated by the "ancestors". However, the system is surly unpredictable after a certain amount of complexity.)
For a bigger truth to exist beyond this simulation, I'd say the purpose and the meaning of the outer world may stay unknown. According to Ockham’s Razor, in case of some theories with the same explanatory strength, the one theory which uses fewer theoretical entities is more likely to be correct. So maybe just accept it that God, religions and their concepts are just some entities expanded by the system itself (maybe by accident or by the attempts of powerful entities within the simulation (Which have evolved to have their own goals and behaviors.))

maybe real God hacked the system?


Since all meanings we know are coded in such simulator

No, not necessarily. That would depend on the question when that simulation started. Like did it start a second ago and all your memories and ideas are hard coded, did it start with your birth, did it start at the dawn of history or are we just exaggerating our own importance and this isn't even about us? Like they could have simulated the big bang which for all intents and purposes is likely the more interesting origin to look at and then their lunch break happened and they didn't press the stop button and in the mean time their simulation ran through 13 billion years worth of iterations.
Like what are the kinds of simulations that we actually run? Well there are two major ones, on the one hand we run scientific simulations in which we put our understanding of physics to the test and ask "what if we take that for granted and just look at what happens?" Or "What if we tweaked this particular parameter". And the other kind of simulations are: Games.
Like seriously the "social simulations" are largely games. In which you either practice a situation to improve for yourself or in which you're asking other people to imagine a scenario and test how they would react to that. Nowadays we might have audiovisual aids for that, but the question is less how a human from the past would behaved, but how WE or our contemporaries would behave in that situation, because they are the puzzle we can't solve. So rather than a scientific simulation so fine grained that it produces consciousness, we would build something like the matrix. So highly plausible VR and either solipsism (single player) or MMORPG and we'd likely just do it for fun.
Also couldn't you come up with plenty of "organic" reasonings for a religion? Like people get born and they die. So you have your start and end points. When they are born they are born completely incapable, into a world of pretty godlike entities. Like seriously they are crazy strong, they can do everything and make things appear out of nowhere they can read your wishes from your eyes or however they do it given that you can't even communicate beyond screaming. Like it's no wonder tons of gods are modeled after parents (either moms or dads or both).
Also they are quite authoritative, like if they allow or forbid something it's literally divine law, until you taste from the tree of enlightenment and figure things out by yourself and are evicted from paradise. So you're pretty much born with that concept, but not in the sense that it's hard coded, it's more like how you are raised and how you grow up.
Similarly it's not far fetched to assume the progression from having figured out how writing works. Like the first generation writes shit down that they think is important, the second generation is instructed about things taking the written notes as reference and by the third generation the first generation is dead and the second has adopted the behavior of treating the writing as source of their law because that's what it was.
Et voilá you've got a holy scripture. Now prophets is just people figuring out what buttons to push for other people. Like they expect their gods to talk to them, their gods aren't doing it, so you talk in the name of their gods and they follow. Et voilá (false) prophets. And so on. It's not actually that hard to imagine the conception of religions from the human condition.
And a fascination with the afterlife. Well given that you see people come from seemingly nowhere or even if you see them getting born it's sort of a miracle. Usually what humans produce is literally shit and sometimes it's not just not shit but also an animal, it's moving, it has a vital force to it, in it. And later in life that "life" is no longer present in the body. So where did it come from? Where is it going to? Like you're faced with literal magic and you're telling me you wouldn't be interested in those questions?

So why do you think the idea of searching for a creator should be reasoned for simulated minds in a simulator?

Who says that it is? Like who says that is what the simulation is about? Like if it started way earlier it might just be an emergent phenomena. Like did you read anything of it before downvoting?

Sorry but you do not seem like you understand my question neither my comment.

@Wiseman A reason for the search of a creator god? How about a similar origin story like for the holy scripture: Artifacts. Like if you found the ruins of a civilization that had built stuff for centuries you'd see a human element in them and so suppose a similarity, yet it would exceed what you are capable of in a lifetime (because it was build over several lifetimes), so you suspect a human like creator, but one a lot more powerful than you are and if you combine it with the rest... So you'd either hide from, evade or search that being.

Bostrom's hypothesis is about a post human simulator / creator. My question is as well.

@Wiseman And you literally have people to this day making arguments that complexity requires a creator god... Which is just trying to apply a learned pattern to other domains. So what is your point?

Its seems so odd to learn a pattern such as God or Creator out of nothing for such unconscious game characters like us in this scenario is true

@Wiseman Ok first of all why would we be unconscious? Like we currently ARE conscious. So either the simulation is really that good or the mind/body dualism folks are correct and we are just experiencing the most immersive VR ever and our actual body is not part of this world just our thoughts. Also why would it result out of nothing. As I tried to explain, it's not actually unreasonable to come up with these concepts out of your own human condition and some hasty generalization, which are probably useful for survival as they might work just good enough.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

All of your arguments are far beyond any scientific reasoning as the hypo itself. More discussion will end nowhere but philo porn since the hypo itself is nothing but thought game. So thank you anyway. I got my answers.

@Wiseman What the hell is "scientific reasoning"? There's a scientific method which employs a cycle of inductive and deductive reasoning, but there's no "scientific reasoning". "Science" and "reasoning" are not just synonyms for smart... Also what kind of science do you expect on the basis of a hypothesis where we're in a simulation and where our creators have so much control that they can and do model our thoughts. Like that kills your ability for empiricism as you can't trust your own perception, so how do you expect science to work in that environment?

I wrote you that ı got my answers for my question.Thank you for your comments.

Because who ever programmed us do have an idea of religion and legitimately believe in a higher power and would deem it necessary for his "creations" to lookup to the original creator i.e., the programmer's creator. Or the simulation that is programmed is a simulation to see the future and so they exact replicated everything but ran the whole simulation on like a 1.5X speed so that they can use the benefit from every prediction to their real world, meaning that their world also have the religions we have and without constituting that it would be incomplete and broken.
